# ValueChanges emits for formControls in component but not formControl in child component?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form within my Angular app that makes use of a few different formControls. Some of them are within the component itself, and some are within a second component that is utilised by the first.

I've found that if the child components alter the value of the form (which I can verify by logging) it doesn't cause the valueChanges observable to emit. But it does alter the form, so surely it should cause the observable to emit?

I have a formGroup in my parent component which contains different formControls, one of them `targetGroups` is passed directly to the child component so that it can manipulate it. This is the one that doesn't cause the valueChanges observable to fire. However if I log the form after using the child component I can see that it's manipulating the form as expected.

Parent Component

```
  @Input() alertData: SafeguardAlert;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      enabled: this.formBuilder.control(this.alertData.enabled),
      frequency: this.formBuilder.control(this.alertData.frequency),
      targetGroups: this.formBuilder.control(this.alertData.targetGroups),
    });

    this.formChange();
  }

  get targetGroups(){
    return this.form.get('targetGroups') as FormControl;
  }

  //TODO :: Temp, remove later
  formChange(){
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

Parent Template

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <div class="alert-body">
        <div class="width-33 mt-md">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>
              Alert Frequency
            </mat-label>
            <mat-select [formControlName]="'frequency'">
              <mat-option [value]="'instant'">
                Instant
              </mat-option>
              <mat-option [value]="'daily'">
                Daily
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
          <app-alert-chip-list [fControl]="targetGroups"></app-alert-chip-list>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </form>
</div>
```

Child Component

```
  @Input() fControl: FormControl;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  pushToFormcontrol(value: any) {
    this.formControlArray.push(value);
  }

  get formControlArray(){
    return this.fControl.value as string[];
  }

  spliceFromFormcontrol(index: number){
    this.formControlArray.splice(index, 1);
  }

  clearInput(ref: HTMLInputElement){
    ref.value = "";
  }
```

Child Template

```
<div class="card chip-list-padding p-sm">
  <div class="flex-row align-items-center">
    <mat-icon class="ml-sm mr-sm">person</mat-icon>
    <mat-chip-list class="flex-row flex-wrap">
      <div class="mr-sm" *ngFor="let element of formControlArray, let i = index">
        <mat-chip [disableRipple]="true" class="chip" >
          <div>
            <span>{{element}}</span>
            <button type="button" mat-icon-button [disableRipple]="true" (click)="spliceFromFormcontrol(i)">
              <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
        </mat-chip>
      </div>
      <div class="chip-list-input-cont">
        <input #listInput class="chip-list-input"
               (keyup.enter)="pushToFormcontrol(listInput.value); clearInput(listInput);">
      </div>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use an event emitter on your child component, and then patch the form on your main component.

Comment: Why should I do it that way instead of the way I've already done it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have some problem here:

```
  pushToFormcontrol(value: any) {
    this.formControlArray.push(value);
  }

  get formControlArray(){
    return this.fControl.value as string[];
  }
```

in this place you directly changed the value of the control, but the value should be updated only through setValue or patchValue, that's why there is no `valueChanges`

your code you should look like

```
  pushToFormcontrol(value: any) {
    this.fControl.patchValue([...formControlArray, value]);
  }

  get formControlArray(){
    return this.fControl.value as string[];
  }

  spliceFromFormcontrol(index: number){
    this.formControlArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

on one more notice, it's better to use formArray, if you have array value:

```
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      enabled: this.formBuilder.control(this.alertData.enabled),
      frequency: this.formBuilder.control(this.alertData.frequency),
      targetGroups: this.formBuilder.array([]),
 });
```

Comment: How would I change my code if I wanted to use a FormArray instead?

Comment: I've changed my code to your suggestions. I now get the valueChanges events but the value isn't added to the formArray.value property.

Comment: Turns out I was trying to manipulate the value of the formArray instead of the formArray's controls. By instead using push() and removeAt() using a FormControl generated with the value received, I get the behaviour I want.

Comment: in this case it would be great, if you check my answer as the right :)